# Magento security scan tool is not identifying patch SUPEE 10415

Tags: security, magento, magento-1.9, patch

We have configured the magento tool to do the security scan weekly. Although we have applied the patch Magento SUPEE 10415 on Magento 1.9.2.0, looks like security tool is not able to scan the applied patch.

I have manually verified and we have patch available in applied.patches.list.

Additionally, I checked with https://www.magereport.com/ and it's able to scan the same patch with no issues.

Any idea what could be the problem with magento security scan tool? do we need to worry about it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?